# Allocate and deallocate memory to static method

Tags: java, android, memory-management, static

May you describe allocating and deallocating memory to a static method when I called it?

```
public class Class1 {

    public static ArrayList<String> method1(Context context) {
        // some variables
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

}
```

I've wrote a simple sample of Static method in Class1 that invoked in a service that works indefinitely!
Now I want to know whether this method removed from memory by the garbage collector?
I've studied about static variables, That once class loader remove from memory, static variables will removed. But what about methods? 
Sorry, I know that my question is not clear, But my mean is in title.

```
public class TestService extends IntentService {

    public TestService() {
        super("test");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {  
        while(true){
            Class1.method1(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allocate something on the heap, and throw away the reference to it, the memory will be deallocated by the garbage collector.

```
while(true) {
    // Allocate a new ArrayList, throw away the return value (a no-op)
    Class1.method1(this);
}
```

Comment: You mean that return value by the method removed from memory by the garbage collector until next loop? And also it's parameters and internal method variables?

Comment: method1 returns a reference to an ArrayList on the heap. If you throw away that reference, there's no way to reach that ArrayList anymore, and the garbage collector will deallocate the memory for that ArrayList. The parameters and method local variables are stored on the stack and are deallocated upon method return.